# Why can you nest aggregate functions when using a window function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand window functions a bit better, and I'm stumped as to why I can't run a nested aggregate function normally, but I *can* when using a window function.

This is the dbfiddle I'm working off of: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=76d62fcf4066053db18783e70269438c

Before running the window function, basically everything else in my query is evaluated (`JOIN` and `GROUP BY`).

So I believe the data the window function is working off of is something like this (after grouping):

[image: the window of data we're working off of]

Or is it something like this?

[image: or is the window of data like this]

So why can I do this: `SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id)) OVER()`, but I can't do it without `OVER()`?

As far as I understand, `OVER()` makes the `SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id))` run on this related data set, but it's still a nested aggregate function.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Because the window functions are applied **after** the group by.

Comment: But so are the aggregate functions without the window function, right? 

Comment: This might help: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=73b9ebfecc8d3ebdc97fc80fd402c073

Comment: Thanks Nick, but not really :( I know that you can't nest aggregate functions, and you can't nest window functions. I'd like to understand why the window function is treated differently than the aggregate on its own. Is my data diagram above regarding the window data correct?

Comment: I've added a potential alternative option to the data that the window function 'sees' in the original post, please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @JoseSalvatierra: no, aggregate functions are evaluated *while* processing the group by. That's why they can't be nested. The window functions are evaluated on the _result_ of the group by.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name! That makes sense. I guess I'd just like to visualize in my mind what that _result of the group by_ looks like. Is it something like my second image above? Or is it more like just the 3rd column of my second image?

Comment: Is `SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id)) OVER()` valid syntax per standard SQL:2016 (or earlier)?

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like `SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id)) OVER()` you can think of `COUNT(votes.option_id)` as a column generated in the `GROUP BY` clause.

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html):

> The rows considered by a window function are those of the “virtual table” produced by the query's FROM clause as filtered by its WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses if any.

This means that window functions operate at a level above the `GROUP BY` clause and any aggregates, and therefore aggregates are available to be used inside window functions.  In your example the "virtual table" corresponds to the second picture.

The reason you cannot nest aggregate functions is that you cannot have multiple levels of `GROUP BY` on the same query.  Similarly you cannot nest window functions.  The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html) is clear on what type of expression are allowed inside aggregate and window functions.  For aggregates functions we can use:

> any value expression that does not itself contain an aggregate expression or a window function call

while for window functions we can use:

> any value expression that does not itself contain window function calls

Comment: "you cannot have multiple levels of GROUP BY on the same query" - well, you can if you want to use GROUPING SETS and the GROUPING function to discover if the column you're interested in is grouped on this row.. But I knew what you meant